# Firebase/firesharp query

Tags: c#, linq, firebase

I have some firebase data structured like this http://www.pcl.dk/firebase.png.
I am trying to return a list of items as specified below.

I am trying to get all the the 'choose1' and 'choose2' for the parent node called '49'. The unique IDs comes from my app, but are not relevant in this query.

I have some code i used before, where i knew the path to the nodes, but since the unique IDs are sort random generated i dont know them in tis setup.

In the code below i am stuck at linq 'Where' clause on how to get the choose1 and choose2 nodes.
Can anyone help?

```
  public class ResultsEntity
    {     
        public string choose1;
        public string choose2;
    }
    public class ResultsFireBaseEntity
    { 
        public string choose1 { get; set; }
        public string choose2 { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<ResultsEntity> GetResults(string weekno)
    {
        List<ResultsEntity> sList = new List<ResultsEntity> { };
        FireSharp.Interfaces.IFirebaseClient _client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(firebaseConfig());
        FireSharp.Response.FirebaseResponse responseResults = _client.Get(weekno);
        var sChoose1 = "";
        var sChoose2 = "";

        try
        {
            List<ResultsFireBaseEntity> listOrderResult = responseResults.ResultAs<List<ResultsFireBaseEntity>>().ToList();
            sChoose1 = listOrderResult.Where(x => x.choose1 != null).Select(x => x.choose1).First();
            sChoose2 = listOrderResult.Where(x => x.choose2 != null).Select(x => x.choose2).First();
            sList.Add(new ResultsEntity { choose1 = sChoose1, choose2 = sChoose2 });
        }
        catch 
        { }
        return sList;
    }
```